# Wrong url is getting picked in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The below is the code where I am picking a txt file from my desktop and have given the correct url.
It was working fine.
Now I have deployed the project on another machine and changed this url accordingly and deployed again.But it is still picking this old url.

I have rebuild the workspace,cleaned the project but still its not working.

```
(window).load(function () {

jQuery.support.cors = true;

var formData = "fileName=plainText.txt&fileLocation=C:\\Users\\rakekaushik\\Desktop\\d";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
```

Comment: Any other suggestions pls.I have a deliverable today.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your browser cache or another browser that you haven't used to look at the page before? If you have Chrome then you can easily test this without clearing any caches by opening a window in incognito mode and testing it that way.

Comment: ANy other suggestions please.I have a deliverable today.

Comment: Ok. Can you add alert("new"); to your file on the new machine with C:\\Users\\arsanu\\Desktop\\d in it and alert("old"); to the file with on the old machine with C:\\Users\\rakekaushik\\Desktop\\d in it? Then run the code again and see if it alerts "old" or "new" to ensure that you server and browser is using the code on the new machine?